# What is the maximum number of files allowed in a HDFS directory?

Tags: filesystems, hadoop, hdfs

What is the maximum number of files and directories allowed in a HDFS (hadoop) directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blocks and files are stored in a HashMap. So you are bound to Integer.MAX_VALUE.
So a directory does not have any limitation, but the whole FileSystem.

Comment: But, the framework might not really scale to that number due to the s/w and the h/w constraints.

Answer (score 13):

In modern Apache Hadoop versions, various HDFS limits are controlled by configuration properties with `fs-limits` in the name, all which have reasonable default values.  This question specifically asked about number of children in a directory.  That's defined by `dfs.namenode.fs-limits.max-directory-items`, and its default value is `1048576`.

Refer to the Apache Hadoop documentation in [hdfs-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) for the full list of `fs-limits` configuration properties and their default values.  Copy-pasting here for convenience:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.fs-limits.max-component-length</name>
  <value>255</value>
  <description>Defines the maximum number of bytes in UTF-8 encoding in each
      component of a path.  A value of 0 will disable the check.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.fs-limits.max-directory-items</name>
  <value>1048576</value>
  <description>Defines the maximum number of items that a directory may
      contain. Cannot set the property to a value less than 1 or more than
      6400000.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size</name>
  <value>1048576</value>
  <description>Minimum block size in bytes, enforced by the Namenode at create
      time. This prevents the accidental creation of files with tiny block
      sizes (and thus many blocks), which can degrade
      performance.</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.fs-limits.max-blocks-per-file</name>
    <value>1048576</value>
    <description>Maximum number of blocks per file, enforced by the Namenode on
        write. This prevents the creation of extremely large files which can
        degrade performance.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.fs-limits.max-xattrs-per-inode</name>
  <value>32</value>
  <description>
    Maximum number of extended attributes per inode.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.fs-limits.max-xattr-size</name>
  <value>16384</value>
  <description>
    The maximum combined size of the name and value of an extended attribute
    in bytes. It should be larger than 0, and less than or equal to maximum
    size hard limit which is 32768.
  </description>
</property>
```

All of these settings use reasonable default values as decided upon by the Apache Hadoop community.  It is generally recommended that users do not tune these values except in very unusual circumstances.

Comment: Does it apply to the / itself? Suppose I set the property to 3, does it means that I can't have more than 3 files under /?

Answer (score 7):

From http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/:

Every file, directory and block in HDFS is represented as an object in the namenode’s memory, each of which occupies 150 bytes, as a rule of thumb. So 10 million files, each using a block, would use about 3 gigabytes of memory. Scaling up much beyond this level is a problem with current hardware. Certainly a billion files is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

This question specifically mentions HDFS, but a related question is how many files can you store on a Hadoop cluster.

That has a different answer if you use MapR's file system.  In that case, billions of files can be stored on the cluster without a problem.

Comment: I would have thought that as CTO of MapR, my own answer would be authoritative enough. In any case, check here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapR_FS] or here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AameZG88t58]

Answer (score 0):

in HDFS, the maximal file name length is 255 bytes. so, the saying about one file object only occupies 150 Bytes are not correct or exact. when calculating the bytes for memory, we should take the maximal occupation of one object.